# gsutil cp fails - "Could not create manifest file"

Tags: google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-platform, gsutil, google-cloud-sdk, google-cloud-shell

I am having some trouble with gsutil copies (that I was using for a bulk transfer of unstructured data to the Google Cloud Storage service.

```
gsutil -m cp -L samsunghd.log -c -p -R ./*.* gs://samsung2101
```

Fails instantly and produces the following error message:

> "CommandException: Could not create manifest file"

It worked once and only once from Cloud Tools for Powershell that I downloaded as part of the entire Google Cloud SDK using the Cloud SDK installer.

After that, all attempts cause the same error - even the transfer of a single file. By eliminating all the other Options, I have been able to isolate it to the -L (logging function).

So, 
    `gsutil -m cp -L samsunghd.log -c -p -R ./*.* gs://samsung2101`

Fails instantly and produces the error message

> "CommandException: Could not create manifest file"

But,     `gsutil -m cp -c -p -R ./*.* gs://samsung2101`

is currently working without problems. Unfortunately, this means I dont get to have log of failures/successful transfers or take advantage of the log-based resume in case of interruption.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. This issue does not seem to have much community discussion / support available.

Many thanks!

Comment: What happens if you specify a manifest file on a different drive/partition? For example gsutil -m cp -L /tmp/samsunghd.log -c -p ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could you try running Powershell as administrator? (Right-click -> run as administrator).

The error is an IO error, so it might be permissions-related

```
 except IOError:
      raise CommandException('Could not create manifest file.')
```

You can find more info at line 3278 on https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gsutil/blob/master/gslib/copy_helper.py

Comment: Many thanks. Changing to "run as administrator" appears to resolve the issue perfectly.